# Always Visible DIV Not working

Tags: html, visible

Hi can some one tell me whats the wrong in the below code?
Trying to make always visible DIV.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">

<head>

    <title>Always Visible Div</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .alwaysVisible {
        position: fixed;
        left: 10px;
        top: 180px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="alwaysVisible">
        Top Left
    </div>

    <div style="height: 2000px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" >
        <p>
            Always visible sample</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: The doctype comes before the opening <html> tag.

Comment: Even I tried now also.. deleted doctype. But no luck :(

Comment: Both divs are always visible. http://jsfiddle.net/UhMBe/1/

Comment: It's working just fine as proved in jsFiddle - so please explain what exactly is the problem.

Comment: same thing I copied but unfortunately not working... wats the wrong I did here

Comment: Nothing wrong. Both div's are visible: http://jsfiddle.net/YaK9L/ What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine in chrome and firefox, I found the issue in IE9, on some googling found that having doctype works, can you try putting

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

This will make IE to run in quirks mode and there by fixing your issue.